# Best approach to implement an accurate recorded stream execution

Tags: java, sleep, timertask

I have a stream of events recorded (for example an `ArrayList<InputEvent>` sorted by `InputEvent.getWhen()`). Differences in time between consecutive events can be of the order of tens of milliseconds.

My goal is to execute ("replay") the recorded stream as accurate as possible, that is, to execute the first event `InputEvent firstEvent` at `long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()`, the second at `startTime + (secondEvent.getWhen() - firstEvent.getWhen())`, and so on.

Of course, the most accurate way would be:

```
execute(ArrayList<InputEvent> stream) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long firstTime = stream.get(0).getWhen();
    for (InputEvent e : stream) {
        while System.currentTimeMillis() < 
                startTime + e.getWhen() - firstTime) {  }
        executeEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Which is a terribly CPU consuming approach, as on the other hand:

```
execute(ArrayList<InputEvent> stream) {
    long lastWhen = strem.get(0).getWhen();
    for (InputEvent e : stream) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(e.getWhen() - lastWhen);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        executeEvent(e);
        lastWhen = e.getWhen();
    }
}
```

is much better with CPU, but is "subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers" (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)).

I also considered TimerTaskExecutor but I think it also uses Thread.sleep and suffers from the same subjectivity issue.

The question is - should I be concerned of the system dependent accuracy causing unexpected flow of the stream? and is there a way to trade accuracy for CPU and get somewhere in between the two examples I gave?

Comment: 1) Have you tested the `Thread.sleep()` on your system, it might work very well - though it is not guaranteed.
2) It looks like you want real-time performance. Java (or .NET for that matter) are not able to give you this performance. The Java community has come up with [Real time Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java), check that out.

Comment: @M.Mimpen - I ended up with `Thread.sleep()` implementation, though it is indeed not as accurate as I would want it to be (some inaccuracies of up to 10ms, which occasionally makes the application make unexpected mistakes). I will look into Real time Java, looks promising!